# Why doesn't justify-content result in space between elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I need free space between the elements. For this I added `justify-content: space-between;` but somehow it doesn't work.

```css
.cards {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial, serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.cards button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.cards button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <img id="coffeeImage1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/180" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
    <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
    <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
    <p id="weight1">weight</p>
    <p id="country1">country</p>
    <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img id="coffeeImage2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/180"" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
    <h1 id="name2">Название</h1>
    <p id="price2" class="price">price</p>
    <p id="weight2">weight</p>
    <p id="country2">country</p>
    <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img id="coffeeImage3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/180"" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
    <h1 id="name3">Название</h1>
    <p id="price3" class="price">price</p>
    <p id="weight3">weight</p>
    <p id="country3">country</p>
    <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

There are so many of them that I have to write each of them. The project uses `HTML` + `CSS` + `JAVASCRIPT` (no frameworks or third-party libraries).

Comment: Seems like you set the parent `cards` width to 40%, which too narrow to see the gutter? try to set the width to 100%

Comment: Yes, why is your container so narrow? Simply removing that rule fixes it. https://jsfiddle.net/skqp18xe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `cards` here is the container (like explained here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

But your class container should not be restrained

```
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

And after you can have the class `card`, meaning the class on your children.

```
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because, the width of the flex-items are not restricted and they are trying to fill up all the space available to them due to their content inside. restricting the widths work.

```css
.cards {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
}

.card{
background-color: red;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 30%;
}


.price {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.cards button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.cards button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1318696/3726/v/450/depositphotos_37267091-stock-illustration-seamless-coffee-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>

<div class="card">
    <img id="coffeeImage2" src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1318696/3726/v/450/depositphotos_37267091-stock-illustration-seamless-coffee-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
    <h1 id="name2">Название</h1>
    <p id="price2" class="price">price</p>
    <p id="weight2">weight</p>
    <p id="country2">country</p>
    <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <img id="coffeeImage3" src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1318696/3726/v/450/depositphotos_37267091-stock-illustration-seamless-coffee-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
    <h1 id="name3">Название</h1>
    <p id="price3" class="price">price</p>
    <p id="weight3">weight</p>
    <p id="country3">country</p>
    <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
</div>
</div>
```